# How can I test a controller that uses identity with a readonly property?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, identity

I have the following code:

```
[Route("resources/avatar")]
[ApiController]
public class AvatarController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext database;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;
    private readonly IUserManagerWrapper userManagerWrapper;

    public AvatarController(IUserManagerWrapper userManagerWrapper, IWebHostEnvironment environment,
        ApplicationDbContext database)
    {
        this.userManagerWrapper = userManagerWrapper;
        this.environment = environment;
        this.database = database;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (User == null) return DefaultImage();

        var user = await this.userManagerWrapper.GetUserAsync(User);
        if ((user?.Avatar?.Length ?? 0) == 0) return DefaultImage();

        return File(user.Avatar, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

I have an issue with testing this `Index Page`.

`User` is a `property` that comes from `ControllerBase` and is of type `ClaimsPrincipal`.

I used a `wrapper` where I would wrap the `usermanager` and then use an `interface` that I would `mock`.

The problem with this approach is I cannot set this `ClaimsPrincipal` to `null` because it is a `read-only`.

This was my test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AvatarController_Should
{
    [Test]
    public async Task IndexReturnsDefaultImage()
    {
        var hostingEnvironmentMock = new Mock<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        var dabataseName = nameof(IndexReturnsDefaultImage);
        var options = AvatarTestUtil.GetOptions(dabataseName);
        var userManagerWrapperMock = new Mock<IUserManagerWrapper>();

        using (var actAndAssertContext = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
        {
            var sut = new AvatarController(userManagerWrapperMock.Object, hostingEnvironmentMock.Object, actAndAssertContext);
        }
     }
}
   public class AvatarTestUtil
   {
    public static DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> GetOptions(string databaseName)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName)
            .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceCollection)
            .Options;
    }
}

}
```

I am open to using a completely new approach.

This was how I used to do test on the `identity` before, but I am stuck now.

Comment: Digging into this question but as a nitpick side note you don't need the `[Route("")]` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for ControllerBase, we can see User is defined as so

```
public ClaimsPrincipal User => HttpContext?.User;
```

So the User actually comes from HttpContext. But HttpContext is readonly as well. Digging into the source code deeper, though, we can see that HttpContext is derived from ControllerContext

```
public HttpContext HttpContext => ControllerContext.HttpContext;
```

Alas! ControllerContext actually has a setter in the concrete implementation!

```
public ControllerContext ControllerContext { get; set; }
```

We could set up a whole new ControllerContext here if we wanted. But we really just need ControllerContext.User. Luckily, that has a setter too. Since you only really need to set the User, we can do so directly here rather than newing up another ControllerContext.

```
using (var actAndAssertContext = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
{
     var sut = new AvatarController(userManagerWrapperMock.Object, hostingEnvironmentMock.Object, actAndAssertContext);
     sut.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User = null;
}
```